# Will my Ubuntu still work when I move my encrypted SSD to a replacement laptop?

Tags: 16.04, encryption

I might have to replace my laptop that's running Ubuntu 16.04 from its SSD. The drive is encrypted, and so is the home directory. If I get a replacement laptop of the same model I would expect just to move the hard drive to the new one and think that it would just work. But the encryption is giving me some doubts.

I originally encrypted using the 15.04 installation and updated to 15.10 and 16.04 since then. I also encrypted my home dir during that original 15.04 installation.

Will the Ubuntu keep working if I stick the encrypted drive into a different laptop of the same type?

Comment: You should ***always*** have a backup of any important files. Especially with encryption and before making big hardware changes - something simple like dropped a drive could be disastrous (ssd's aren't immune to breaking either).  Just in case anything goes wrong it's only inconvenient then.

Comment: @Xen2050 indeed that is a good warning. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, it will.

If your SSD is hardware encrypted, the new laptop you're moving it [will need to support SED](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Introduction-to-Self-Encrypting-Drives-SED-557/), which, in your case, is no problem, since you will be putting it into another laptop of the same make / model.

If you only have home directory encryption (Set up with "Encrypt my home folder" during installation), or another form of software-only encryption, you can move your SSD around as you wish, and it will work in any computer.

Comment: I don't think it has SED enabled. I checked with the guide you linked. I was using the drive encryption that Ubuntu offered when I installed my 15.04. I also used home directory encryption, but those are two different things. Will that make a difference?

Comment: @simbabque, No, it won't, and you'll be able to use your SSD in your new laptop. Both the encryption options which Ubuntu offers (the full disk one, and the home directory one), are software only, so you'll be fine.